# How to install and use VS Code Icon Fonts

Tags: html

I want to believe that the best way of using icons in VS code is via the icon fonts extension (tell me if I'm wrong). Before now, I used to download icons in .png format before using them. The problem is that, the whole process of setting-up the extension (found in [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=idleberg.icon-fonts) and [open-vsx](https://open-vsx.org/extension/idleberg/icon-fonts)) for use doesn't seem to be clear (especially for a newbie like me). Please, I need a step by step explanation on how to go about this.
OR
If there exist a better alternative let me know. Thank you.

Comment: What is unclear about the extension usage?

Comment: OK. Let's focus on the installation.

Comment: Go to the extensions pane in vsc and type `idleberg.icon-fonts` in the search bar.  Click install.  In the future, [I recommend you read the manual](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery).

Answer (score -1):

in my opinion, if you use an icon with a .png file format, then it will obviously slow down the performance of your website. do you already know about CSS framework that works with icons? I'll give you a few CSS framework references that work on handling the icons you need

https://fontawesome.com/

https://www.glyphicons.com/

https://materialdesignicons.com/

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure many of the icons are not free especially in Font Awesome.